# How do I use a permission created by config.py and __init__.py (using paster) in browser/configure.zcml for a custom permission?

Tags: plone

I'm using paster to create my content types and views. I'm using Plone 3.3.

In my `config.py`:

```
ADD_PERMISSIONS = {
    # -*- extra stuff goes here -*-
    'MyContentType': 'mynamespace.mypackage: Add My Content Type'
}
```

In my `__init__.py`:

```
for atype, constructor in zip(content_types, constructors):
    utils.ContentInit('%s: %s' % (config.PROJECTNAME, atype.portal_type),
        content_types=(atype, ),
        permission=config.ADD_PERMISSIONS[atype.portal_type],
        extra_constructors=(constructor,),
        ).initialize(context)
```

...and in `browser/configure.zcml`:

```
  <browser:page
      for="*"
      name="myview"
      class=".myview.MyView"
      template="myview.pt"
      allowed_interface=".myview.IMyView"
      permission="the permissions defined in ADD_PERMISSIONS: what is the name I can put here?"
      />
```

I know I can create custom permissions using [colective.autopermission](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/permissions), but I I already created them using config.py, how can I use them in my configure.zcml?

**EDIT**: Hum, browser views defined in ZCML use the Zope 3 permission id, but my config.py is using the Zope 2 permission title. I need to use collective.autopermission to create the zope 3 permission id, or can I use another approach (like just creating a permissions.zcml, with `title` attributes, using the same `title` provided in `ADD_PERMISSIONS` dict, because the permissions in zope 2 style are already created so I don't need collective.autopermission)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should indeed use collective.autopermission and create a permissions.zcml (and load that in your configure.zcml, or just add the lines in configure.zcml itself) that contains statements like this:

```
  <permission
      id="mynamespace.mypackage.AddMyContentType"
      title="mynamespace.mypackage: Add My Content Type"
      />
```

You can pick a different id, but the title needs to be the same as the title you have given in config.py.

EDIT:

Note that Zope2 versions in use in Plone 4.0 or higher have the collective.autopermission patches included so you do not need to use that package anymore; you *do* still need the permission declaration in zcml of course.

On Plone 3 you do need the collective.autopermission package and you should depend on it in your setup.py and add `<include package="collective.autopermission" />` in your zcml before the permissions registration (or use z3c.autoinclude, included in Plone 3.3, to load that zcml automatigically).

Comment: But should I remove the config.py section? Or can I keep it? What I understand is: use autopermission to avoid using the approach in config.py and __init__.py. But my doubt is, if I'm alreadin using the config.py approach, should I stop using it and only use the autopermission, or can I use a permission.zcml (and in title attribute I use the one in config.py), without autopermission?

Comment: You still need it in the `__init__.py` so you still need it in config.py.

Comment: Note that you may want to just protect your view with the `zope2.View` permission instead, or create a specific permission in zcml with title 'View My Content Type' instead.

Comment: Ok, I still need them in `__init__.py`, and in `config.py`, so the permissions.zcml are going to be used only so I can have Zope 3 permission id, and use it in the configure.zcml. Is that correct?

Comment: I tested, adding only the permission I would like to have a Zope 3 id, and ir worked. Do you see any problems? (Besides a bad design, since now there are two places with permissions configs. I'm asking from a 'bug' or 'incompatibility' perspective.)

Comment: You mean you removed the permission from config.py? You still need some permission to put in the call in `__init__.py`, right? Other than that I see no problem.

Comment: No, I didn't remove. `config.py` and `__init__.py` are as is. I've read `collective.autopermission` source code, and it checks if a permission exists before adding it again, so I don't think it'll have problems,so I'm just asking for more experienced people if they can see a problem in the future I can't see now when using this approach. :)